# sort w/ left join laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to join the row (subcomment) that has the max marks so I tried this

```
$comments=$comments->leftJoin('sub_comments', function($join){
    $join->on('comments.id', '=', 'sub_comments.comment_id');
    $join->where('sub_comments.marks', '=', function($q){
      $q->from('sub_comments')->selectRaw('max(marks)');
    });
```

and I get this

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

is there any way I can do this? I appreciate any helpful answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the full code, you're missing closing brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding a hasMany relationship to the Model of the comments then I sorted the sub_comments ( second table «right table» ) inside the model like that

```
return $this->hasMany('App\SubComment')->orderBy('sub_comments.marks');
```

and it is working good